# Sharepoint RequestDigest is interpreted as parameter in cURL

Tags: rest, curl, sharepoint, talend, rhel

I use the following sequence of cURL commands to upload files to Sharepoint.

```
# Get Token
curl -X POST -d "" --ntlm -u usr:pw http://.../_api/contextinfo
# Checkout File
curl -X POST -d "" -H "X-RequestDigest: 0x...,11 Sep 2020 14:45:30 -0000" --ntlm -u usr:pw "http://.../_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('...')/checkOut()"
# Upload File
curl --ntlm -u usr:pw --upload-file ... http://...
# Check In
curl -X POST -d "" -H "X-RequestDigest: 0x...,11 Sep 2020 14:45:30 -0000" --ntlm -u usr:pw "http://.../_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('...')/checkIn(comment='Comment',checkInType=0)"
```

That works fine when running locally using libcurl. It does not when running on RHEL7. Then the ' -0000' within the header's token is interpreted as parameter resulting in the error message below.

```
curl: option -0000': is unkown
```

I cannot remove the space or minus because it is part of the token. I already tried to escape the header in several ways without success. Do you have an idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: in tSystem component, are you using a single command or an array of command ?

Comment: I tried both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are invoking curl over SSH, like this:

```
ssh $host curl -X POST -d "" -H "X-RequestDigest: 0x...,11 Sep 2020 14:45:30 -0000" --ntlm -u usr:pw "http://.../_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('...')/checkIn(comment='Comment',checkInType=0)"
```

This does not work because SSH does not transmit the argument vector as an array of strings. Instead, it transmits a single string, consisting of all the argument separated by spaces. Instead you have to write something like this:

```
ssh $host "curl -X POST -d \"\" -H \"X-RequestDigest: 0x...,11 Sep 2020 14:45:30 -0000\" --ntlm -u usr:pw \"http://.../_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('...')/checkIn(comment='Comment',checkInType=0)\""
```

(Note that specifying passwords on the command line may be insecure because the arguments are visible using `ps`.)

Comment: I am running the commands within a Talend ETL Job using their tSystem component. Please note that step 'Get Token' and 'Upload File' are running fine. Furthermore I get a 403 response from Sharepoint if I remove the space in front of the minus.

Comment: I think this is more of a Talend question. It probably needs some similar form of quoting.